# Trying to connect VBA with FileMaker (runtime error 80004005)

Tags: sql, vba, odbc, filemaker

I really don't have idea of what I'm doing wrong here. I want to connect VBA with FileMaker Pro 11 through ODBC driver. I have installed the driver and it works. The FileMaker ODBC is able to detect my database. So, after configuring the DSN with name "FM", I wrote the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim counter As Integer

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    cn.Open "DRIVER={FileMaker ODBC};Data Source=FM;Initial Catalog='test.fp7';UID=admin;PWD=admin;"
    cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    sql = "SELECT col_name FROM test.fp7 WHERE col_name='value'"
    rs.Open sql, cn

    For Each it In rs.Fields
        Name = it.Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = Name
    Next
End Sub
```

Here it comes the most strange thing: when I'm executing the code, it establish the connection with the server, but the database (Initial Catalog='test.fp7') is not setting up. Instead, in the variable inspector, it appears the name of 't', the first letter of 'test.fp7'. I have tested this with other name ('other_test.fp7') and again it takes the first letter 'o'. Therefore, the recordset instruction fails with runtime error 80004005. Why only takes the first letter?? Please, I'm completely shocked!

I also configured a MySQL database to test the communication between VBA and MySQL and worked great with a similar code.

Any help will be well received. Thanks in advance!

David

--------   EDIT   --------

I forgot the semicolon in the sql query...Kid fail. Never mind, with the semicolon the error change to "runtime error 80040e09".

Comment: what happens if you remove the single quotes from `test.fp7` and just do `Catalog=test.fp7:`? Also, maybe worth trying without that parameter and relying on the default just to test it

Comment: Nothing happens, the database keeps being 't'.

Comment: If I only specify "Catalog", VBA does not detect neither the 't'. (DefaultDatabase="")

Comment: hm. what is the actual database name? You know there is a `Database:` parameter and the initial catalog is different from database name?

Comment: I didn't know that. Anyway, if I set database to "test.fp7", the result of DefaultDatabase is "".

Comment: If after the opening of the ADODB.connection I set conn.DefaultDatabase = "test.fp7" the result is "t" again.

Comment: Could be a problem with the VBA references? I have included the "Microsoft Active X Data Object 2.7".

Comment: i dont think so but try ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 library

Comment: Same problem, same error.

Comment: after you connect with `cn.open (conString)` just stop there and put a breakpoint, and add to watch window (right click cn and add watch). then when you debug your code with F5 just stop at the watch window and iterate through properties and see what the conn actually hold, the data etc. This is part of basic debugging process if you can't do that I don't think I can help you much

Comment: There are exactly 92 properties related with the driver, the server, the database, versions, etc. I can't type them here. I don't see anything wrong, just the problem of not being able to connect to the database. The host name, user_id and password, the odbc driver, everything is ok. There are 2 properties (I don't know if they are related with the problem) called Schema Term and Usage. If you need more information, please tell me. And thank you for your help.

Comment: do you have SSMS? can you make make a screenshot of your Object Explorer?

Comment: I don't have SSMS. What do you mean with Object Explorer? Is it the list of the vba objects? Or those related with ADODB?

Comment: in SSMS when you connect to a SQL instance you can view/navigate via Object Explorer. Thats normally where I verify things like connection, database schemas, tables, names etc

Comment: Ok, but what if the database is not SQL-based, like FileMaker?

Comment: I downloaded SSMS but it is not connecting to any database I have set, neither FileMaker nor MySQL.